# I am not a student of medicine but a research scientist in Algorithms. I wish to contribute to medicine and am looking for a starting point.

Tags: computers, diagnosis, tuberculosis

I wish to understand tuberculosis and contribute to its research, though I am open to other problems. How should I start? I do not wish to join any university. I wish to do it as my side-project.

Comment: Unfortunately, this type of question is too broad to be answered properly, as there is no one right answer. However, it is an important question, and if you could rephrase it to a question that can be answered, it may be very useful to a lot of people.

Comment: Help me rephrase it. I am trying to dive into an area where I have zero information.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wish to contribute to research, I suggest you go to [PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/) and read as many recent papers published on the topic to acquaint yourself with the latest developments to see if there is anything that you can contribute towards.